# "Number of requests it responds per second" vs "Number of requests it responds to per second"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Which one of the following is grammatically correct?

> Number of requests it responds per second

or

> Number of requests it responds to per second

Here I am talking about computer servers. These servers respond to each and every request they receive. Honestly both the sentences sound wrong to me.

Note: `request` and `respond` are technical terms and so I can't replace them with any other word.

Comment: I think your constraint is wrong. "responds" is not the correct technical term to use here. I would use "handle".

Comment: We don't say *Our complaints department **respond requests** for replacement products* with no preposition. The same applies to your example - the preposition *should* be included.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) certainly uses the terminology "response."

Comment: Yes. A site handles a request and returns a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option ("requests it responds per second") is not correct.
The second option ("requests it responds to per second") is correct.

You could also flip it slightly and say "requests to which it responds per second," if you don't like the sound of the second option.